# How to make Testing with Angular 6 and Apollo client for GraphQl

Tags: testing, karma-jasmine, angular6, apollo

I'm trying to make test development with Angular 6 and GraphQl but we really don't know how to do as the best way possible. I have tried to find something on the internet that explains this, but nothing really good has been found.

I'll post my case here looking for someone who could help me to do, or someone who could tell me any tutorial/web to find more and good information.

**The problem**

I want to test an Auth. I have an *auth.service.js* and the respective *spec.js*. You can see it below:

**AUTH_SERVICE_TS**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as UserActions from './../../store/user/actions';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    user;

    constructor(private store: Store<any>, private apollo: Apollo, private router: Router) {
        this.store.select('state').subscribe(state => this.user = state);
    }

    /**
     * Function that check the email and password for login
     * @param email
     * @param password
     */
    login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.apollo.mutate({
            mutation: this.loginRequestGql(),
            variables: {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        }).subscribe(value => {
            const data = value.data.login;

            this.saveUserData(data);
            this.router.navigate(['/app']);
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function that save user data in the store and in the session storage
     * @param data
     */
    saveUserData(data) {
        this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.Login({token: data.token}));
        this.setSessionStorage(this.user);
    }

    /**
     * Function that remove user info in the store
     */
    logout() {
        this.store.dispatch(new UserActions.Logout());
        this.setSessionStorage(this.user);
    }

    /**
     * Function that create the request with Graphql sintax
     */
    loginRequestGql() {
        return gql`
            mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
                login(email: $email, password: $password) {
                    token
                }
            }
        `;
    }

    /**
     * Function that save in the session storage the data parameter
     * @param data
     */
    setSessionStorage(data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

**AUTH_SERVICE_SPEC_TS**

```js
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ApolloTestingController, ApolloTestingModule } from "apollo-angular/testing";
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducer } from '../../store/user/reducer';

describe('AuthService', () => {
    let backend: ApolloTestingController;
    let authService: AuthService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ RouterTestingModule, ApolloTestingModule, StoreModule.forRoot({ state: reducer }) ],
            providers: [ AuthService,
                { provide: ApolloTestingModule, useClass: ApolloTestingModule }
            ]
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        backend = TestBed.get(ApolloTestingController);
        authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    });

    it('should be created', inject([AuthService], (service: AuthService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should test login', (done) => {
        const email = 'diego@mail.com';
        const password = '123456';

        // const a = authService.login(email, password);
        // expect(a).toBe(TEST_RESPONSE['data'].login.token);
        // authService.login(email, password);
        // backend.expectOne(authService.loginRequestGql).flush(TEST_RESPONSE);
    });
});

const TEST_RESPONSE: Object = {
        "data": {
            "login": {
                "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjZjZDBjMDMXX0.as7-r_nlYfJ2w3CfOqwtLcTlBg5LrwFcm_ZXZ_GzCl5Qq0GS92r5tqGJtFzRfG02PPoLZ8uwsbgLj-5v2pYBXHjBLZvbjnW_zgXRLoDEcrBDpfPAoVH85ca_hb_xVaIgEUGumUPfn2IOx0Ce8fLlqtWGqoWtWzcCE
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance to the community!! Hope you can help me!!

PD: If you need more information, just request and i'll give.

Answer (score 2):

In one of recent versions of `apollo-angular` we released a testing utilities. Testing technique is pretty much similar to how you test HttpClient in Angular.

To learn more about how to test components and services that uses Apollo, please read the official documentation about it.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/guides/testing.html

Comment: We can't find usefull tests about mutation requests. Perhaps, my error is about concepts and i can't create directly mutation test.

Comment: @DiegoGalocha there is no example test of mutation but you can test it exactly the same as queries, by operation name, by document.

Comment: This was very helpful! Although the link is broken, here is the updated link:
https://apollo-angular.com/docs/development-and-testing/testing

Answer (score 1):

It seems we cannot use `expectOne` with a simple `DocumentNode` parameter when doing a mutation.
So instead of:

```
backend.expectOne(authService.loginRequestGql).flush(TEST_RESPONSE);
```

we must pass to `expectOne` a function which asserts the operation's query definition is the expected one:

```
backend.expectOne((operation) => {
    expect(operation.query.definitions).toEqual(mutation.definitions);
    return true;
})
.flush(TEST_RESPONSE);
```